# Connect Glue to RDS, S3 and Secrets manager from VPC

Tags: aws-glue

I need my Glue job to access a VPC accessible RDS, s3 bucket and Secrets Manager.

I've created a JDBC connection and verified that it works fine. I've also created a network connection and verified that it has access to the required s3 bucket. These were both confirmed using the "Test connection" feature in the AWS UI.

When I create a Glue job, I can add multiple connections. I add both connections.

If I add the network connection first, I can successfully connect to s3 but the connection to SecretsManager times out. If I add the JDBC connection first the s3 connection fails but the SecretsManager and RDS connection work fine.

Is there something I'm missing in terms of this configuration? Are multiple connections *actually* supported or it a UI bug that I can add multiple?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Do you use private or public subnet to connect to with the glue?

Comment: @Marcin: private subnet

Comment: Does your VPC have NAT gateway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was pretty ignorant of Glue when I asked above.

I only needed a single connection, of type "Network" to allow access to the 3 resources that I outlined above.

Once this connection was correctly configured (and by correctly I mean Security Groups and ACL access were in place) I could access:

- my RDS (in another private subnet in the VPC)
- S3 (via correctly configured VPC Gateway)
- SecretsManager (via correctly configured VPC Gateway)

IMVHO, the "JDBC connection" feature is a little confusing - at least it was for me. It is *not * required to access a Database. It is a "special" type of Network connection which can be used to store credential info as metadata on the connection object (check with your security folks before you do this - I don't know how this is stored on the AWS backend).

Anyway, Glue wasn't the issue here - my own ignorance was.